# How to grep result of ls in Turtle

Tags: haskell, haskell-turtle

I'm playing with [Turtle](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/turtle-1.0.0) and I'm faced with the following problem.

I want to do something like (in shell)

```
ls | grep 'foo'
```

My attempt using Turtle is

```
grep (prefix "foo") (ls ".") & view
```

But I got the following message

```
Couldn't match type ‘Turtle.FilePath’ with ‘Text’
Expected type: Shell Text
  Actual type: Shell Turtle.FilePath
In the second argument of ‘grep’, namely ‘(ls ".")’
In the first argument of ‘(&)’, namely
  ‘grep (prefix "foo") (ls ".")’
```

I understand `ls` returns `FilePath`  whereas `grep` works on `Text`, so what can I do ?

## Update

There are obviously solutions which involves converting back and forth from `FilePath` to `Text`. That's beyond the simplicity I would expect shell-like program.

Someone mentioned the `find` function, which somehow could solves the problem.
However `find` is the equivalent to the `find` shell function and I was trying just to do `ls | grep "foo"`. I'm not trying to solve a real life problem (if I were, I would switch to bash instead) but trying to combine simple bricks as I would do in bash. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem that bricks in Turtle are that easy to combine :-(.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of [`grep`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/turtle-1.0.0/docs/Turtle-Prelude.html#v:grep), we can use [`match`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/turtle-1.0.0/docs/Turtle-Pattern.html#v:match), in combination with the [`MonadPlus`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#t:MonadPlus) instance of `Shell` for filtering:

```
filterByPattern :: MonadPlus m => Pattern x -> FilePath -> m FilePath
filterByPattern somepattern somepath =
    case match somepattern (either id id (toText somepath)) of
        []        -> mzero
        otherwise -> return somepath

greppedls :: FilePath -> Pattern x -> Shell FilePath
greppedls somepath somepattern = 
   ls somepath >>= filterByPattern somepattern
```

**Edit:** Instead of using the unnecesarily general `MonadPlus`, here's an implementation that filters using the turtle-specific combinator [`select`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/turtle-1.0.0/docs/Turtle-Shell.html#v:select):

```
filterByPattern :: Pattern x -> FilePath -> Shell FilePath
filterByPattern somepattern somepath =
    case match somepattern (either id id (toText somepath)) of
        []        -> select []         -- no matches, so filter this path  
        otherwise -> select [somepath] -- let this path pass
```

A value `foo :: Shell a` is a bit like a "list of `a`s". If we have a function `genlist :: a -> Shell b` that for each `a` generates a (perhaps empty!) list of `b`s, we can obtain a list of `b`s using the `(>>=)` operator: `foo >>= genlist`.

**Edit#2**: The standard turtle function [`find`](http://hayoo.fh-wedel.de/?query=Pattern%20x%20-%3E%20FilePath%20-%3E%20Shell%20FilePath) already filters files using a pattern. It is recursive and searches in subdirectories.

Comment: Your code might compiles but doesn't work. `repr (Filepath "foo")` doesn't return `"foo"` but `"Filepath \"foo\"` which means `prefix "foo"` won't match `foo` files. Also `Turtle` claims to be a better bash. This bit of code is much too complicated compared to is bash equivalent `ls | grep "foo"`.

Comment: @mb14 I have removed the `repr` issue by using [`toText`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/system-filepath-0.4.13.4/docs/Filesystem-Path-CurrentOS.html#v:toText) instead.

Comment: @mb14 As for the overcomplication, perhaps something like `filterByPattern` should be in the library (or perhaps it already is, and I haven't seen it). Once such a function exists, `ls "." >>= filterByPattern "foo"` is not much worse than `ls | grep "foo"`.

Comment: I kind of agree, however, `grep` already exists and do the same. It probably will be better to just have `type FilePath = Text` as other filepath library do. Or maybe a function which *lift* text functions to filepath functions.

Comment: About the complexity, If I'll have to do that for such a simple bash task I'm better using just plain IO, regexp etc  and not bother with Turtle.

Comment: @mb14 It appears there already is a standard turtle function that filters paths by pattern. I searched [Hayoo](http://hayoo.fh-wedel.de/) for the type `Pattern x -> FilePath -> Shell FilePath` and [this function](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/turtle-1.2.1/docs/Turtle-Prelude.html#v:find) came up. It searches recursively, however.

Answer (score 1):

To convert from FilePath into Text you use:

```
fp :: Format r (FilePath -> r)
```

Here is an example:

```
format fp ("usr" </> "lib")
```

There is a couple of issues about this so Gabriel has decided to update the tutorial a few days ago:

https://github.com/Gabriel439/Haskell-Turtle-Library/commit/a2fff2acf912cc7adb2e02671340822feb0e9172

To answer your (updated) question, the best I can come up is:

```
format fp <$> ls "." & grep (has "foo") & view
```

`&` is playing the role of `|`.

As a personal note, it is of course not as short as `ls | grep 'foo'` but still quite elegant given that Haskell is a typed language.

Comment: As of 2021, the type of `grep` seems to have changed and this solution is not type correct anymore: `format fp <$> ls "."` has type `Shell Text` instead of `Shell Line` as expected by `grep (has "foo")`. This however works: `unsafeTextToLine <$> format fp <$> ls "." & grep (has "ver") & view`.

Answer (score 1):

The literal answer is this one-liner:

```
example =
    view (ls "." & fmap (format fp) & grep (prefix "foo") & fmap toText)
```

The idiomatic answer is to use the `find` utility

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [`repr`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/turtle-1.0.0/docs/Turtle-Format.html#v:repr)

```
repr :: Show a => a -> Text
```

Comment: +1 Not bad but that solve half of the problem. Let's suppose I want to move the selected file somewhere, then I need to convert them back to `FilePath`.

Comment: `repr` works in ghci but I can't find it on the link you provided.

Comment: @mb14 I've edited the answer to include the correct link. Also note that `repr = format w` where `format` is described [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/turtle-1.0.0/docs/Turtle-Format.html#v:format).

Comment: `repr` is not good then. It's equivalent to show, and add quotes and stuff.